# Elasticsearch Python client Reindex Timedout

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to reindex using the Elasticsearch python client, using https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.reindex. But I keep getting the following exception: `elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeout`

The stacktrace of the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/es_test.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "~/es_test.py", line 30, in main
    target_index='users-2')
  File "~/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 306, in reindex
    chunk_size=chunk_size, **kwargs)
  File "~/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 182, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "~/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 124, in streaming_bulk
    raise e
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeout(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myhost', port=9243): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))
```

Is there anyway to prevent this exception besides increasing the timeout?

**EDIT:** python code

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection, helpers

es = Elasticsearch(connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
                   host='myhost',
                   port=9243,
                   http_auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password),
                   use_ssl=True,
                   verify_certs=True,
                   timeout=600)
helpers.reindex(es, source_index=old_index, target_index=new_index)
```

Comment: Can you show you python code?

Comment: @Val I included my code

Comment: Can you try to add the [`chunk_size`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.reindex) parameter (maybe with value = 100) in the `reindex` call?

Comment: Use the `chunk_size` and you should be fine. I have been able to reindex millions of documents using a simple reindex call. **Example:** `helpers.reindex(es, source_index=old_index, target_index=new_index, chunk_size=1000)`

Answer (score 1):

I have been suffering from this issue for couple of days, I changed the request_timeout parameter to 30 (which is 30 seconds) didn't work.
Finally I have to edit the stream_bulk and reindex APIs inside the elasticsearch.py

Change the chunk_size parameter from the default 500 (which is processing 500 documents) to less number of documents per batch. I changed mine to 50 which worked fine for me. No more read timeout errors.

def streaming_bulk(client, actions, **chunk_size=50**, raise_on_error=True,
        expand_action_callback=expand_action, raise_on_exception=True,
        **kwargs):

def reindex(client, source_index, target_index, query=None, target_client=None,
        **chunk_size=50**, scroll='5m', scan_kwargs={}, bulk_kwargs={}):

Comment: where can I find the elasticsearch,py?

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening because of the OutOfMemoryError for Java heap space, which means you are not giving elasticsearch enough memory for what you want to do.
Try to look at your `/var/log/elasticsearch` if there is any exception like that.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2636